# MySQL DISTINCT date only returning 1 value for particular table. Same query works on other tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with the exact same structure:

```
date (date)
title (varchar 275)
```

Both tables have rows for dates including 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31

If I run this query on table1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table1 WHERE date IN ('2021-01-02', '2021-01-04')
```

it returns the expected values of:

```
2021-01-02
2021-01-04
```

However, if I run it on table2 I only get 1 result which is the earliest date in the range. For example if I run the same query I only get 2021-01-02. If I change the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table2 WHERE date IN ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06')
```

I only get 2021-04-04. If I change the dates to '2021-01-06' and '2021-01-07' I only get 2021-01-06, etc, etc.

If I run the exact same query on table1, it returns all expected values. I assume it must be a difference in the tables but they have the exact same fields, field types, db collation, etc. It behaves as if there is a LIMIT 1.

EDIT @Joseph:
If I remove the DISTINCT and run the following query:

```
SELECT date FROM table2 WHERE date IN ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06')
```

it returns the correct dates(duplicated):

```
2021-01-04
2021-01-04
2021-01-04
...
2021-01-06
2021-01-06
```

Adding the DISTINCT back in results in(only for table2):

```
2021-01-04
```

Comment: the second query is running on `table1`, not `table2` as you mentioned

Comment: Typo. Fixed. In table2 the data exists- the DISTINCT however is only returning 1 value.

Comment: could you remove `DISTINCT` from the second query and double-check if it works

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. In that case it does in fact return rows that include all dates. Just duplicated.

Comment: could you add this result wihtout `DISTINCT` if it possible

Comment: Does `SELECT date FROM table2 WHERE date IN ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06') GROUP BY date`  work?  My guess is table 2 doesn't have a `2021-01-06' value in the tables.  or it's a timestamp field and none of them are exactly at midnight.  maybe where `date(Date) in ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06')`  using date function to truncate time... if time component exists.

Comment: @xQbert Yes, I tried adding GROUP BY date. It returns the same result. The date is type date not datetime or timestamp. All values exist in both tables. I can confirm this by changing the query in table2 to date = '2021-01-06' or any date and it returns results.

Comment: What happens if your 'in' is just for '2021-01-06'?  `WHERE date IN ('2021-01-06')`

Comment: try this one `SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table2 WHERE Date(date) IN ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06')`

Comment: @xQbert if it's only a single date IN () then it returns the correct result.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow  so then you're right it has to be doing a TOP or LIMIT or something to return only 1 distinct record.  The where clause is workng... it allows for both but something is preventing multiple values from being returned...  TOP? Limit? is this going though something which limits the results or straight in a query window?  Very unique issue indeed.  corrupted index on date on table 2?  but that's a stretch...  Lateral join limiting to top 1?

Comment: @Joseph running your query returns the correct result which is confusing to me. That would imply the data is not already of type date? How would that be possible if the field is type date. Also, it makes the query significantly slower.

Comment: "Date" includes time.  you have time components on those reocrds you can't see as the ui is not including the time in the rendering of the data.   Format the data to include time and you'll see the problem. but then... that doesn't explain why limiting to just 1 day worked in where clause... `DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')`

Comment: @xQbert I'm trying that now. Seems like I'm learning something new today about how dates are stored. When the date is inputted there is no time involved at all.

Comment: @xQbert no rows have any time value. All are 00:00:00

Comment: This seems like a bug at this point.  do you have a create table statement & Sample data?  I'd like to re-create this on a db.fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you need to convert your `date` column to the actual date so you could do that like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table2 WHERE Date(date) IN ('2021-01-04', '2021-01-06')
```

Answer (score 1):

if your ***date*** column is **string(varchar) data type**.

Try this

```
SELECT district date 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
   STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN CAST('2021-01-04' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-01-06' AS DATE)
```

or
if your ***date*** column is **date data type.**

Try this

```
SELECT district date 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
   date BETWEEN CAST('2021-01-04' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-01-06' AS DATE)
```